# Xcode horizontal UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I have 4 buttons in a `UIViewController` in XCode. I already added code to them so I would prefer to keep the buttons. I want to have the buttons side by side in the view where there is only one button on the screen at a time and the edge of the other buttons on the edge of the screen. Where you can just barely see them. I wanted to know how would I be able to accomplish this? If you need more information than this just let me know?

Comment: What's the _question_?

Comment: I'd start with UICollectionViewController

Comment: FryAnEgg was right... you should dig into UICollectionView.

Comment: I have other buttons in the view that I don’t want a Horizontal Scroll View on would that affect it.

Comment: Please post UI if you have and elaborate your.

Comment: This is a standard use-case for using a UICollectionView without much trouble, keep the flow layout and set the scroll direction to horizontal. Then, just create as many UICollectionViewCells as buttons wish to display. With this setup, if you "shrink" the cell's width to be a bit shorter than device width you'll achieve your desired UI across all devices. I wouldn't go with a UIScrollView like suggested below, a UICollectionView gives you a lot more for free.

Comment: Post a sample UI that you are trying to make. else every body is just making guesses on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!


 private func addButton() {
        for index in 0...2{
            let button = UIButton()
            let x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            button.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

            button.backgroundColor = UIImage(named: ColorArr[index])

            scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index + 1)
            scrollView.addSubview(button)


        }
    }
```

You can call this function in `viewDidLoad()` and i took color array to differentiate buttons